# Error: "the term is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have written a basic script to execute and send an email with an attachment, I have tested this in PowerShell. However when I try to create this as a task scheduler I get the following error:

[image]

However my exact same code executes without issue in PowerShell.

[image]

This is my view in task scheduler:
[image]

What am I missing? I have set the execution policy so that is not an issue and I've tested my code and there is no issue there.

Comment: Hi, I renamed my folder powershell script without a space and this resolved the issue. However I don't understand as I believed the & with "" would mean this wasn't an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-File` parameter instead:

```
-File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"
```

PowerShell's call operator (`&`) works only inside PowerShell, so you would need to put it inside the argument string:

```
"& 'C:\path\to\your.ps1'"
```

While that would work too, it has certain disadvantages, most importantly that it will return only 0 (success) or 1 (failure) as the exit code, but not the actual exit code of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument needs to include the `-Command` parameter, not just the code you want to run.  Also, your code to run needs to be a string, not raw Powershell code, or the command line will try to interpret it.  Set the argument to:

```
-Command '&"C:\Users\Martyn\Documents\Powershell Scripts\Working.ps1"'
```

Or, you can try the `-File` parameter directly, although there are known issues with it:

```
-File "C:\Users\Martyn\Documents\Powershell Scripts\Working.ps1"
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is getting this error, you need to install `ProcessMitigation` into PowerShell before you can use it. By default, it's not there.

Steps to install:

- Run Powershell with administrative rights.
- Run `Save-Module -Name ProcessMitigations -Path <path>` command in PS to download the component. Provide actual path instead of  to download.
- Run `Install-Module -Name ProcessMitigations` in PS to install it.

More [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ProcessMitigations/1.0.7).